# How to pack three unsigned integers into an unsigned short in C

Tags: c, int, short, packing

I have an assignment from college, in which I have to use **C** to pack three unsigned integers representing a date (the year must be between 1970 and 2097) and compress it into an unsigned short, then unpack it again and show it in command line.

Can someone help me please?

Below I leave the code I have so far (declared variables outside functions and function signatures cannot be changed)

Edit: I have a second problem, which is the getchar function not return anything, setting the three date fields to 0...

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned short pkdate_t;
typedef struct date3 {
    unsigned year;
    unsigned month;
    unsigned day;
} date3_t;

int ror (int val, unsigned n) {
    return (val >> n)|(n << (32 - n));
}

int pack_date (pkdate_t * dst, date3_t * src) {
    if ((*src).year < 1097 || (*src).year > 2097 || (*src).month < 1 || (*src).month > 12 || (*src).day < 1 ||
    ((*src).month == 2 && (((*src).year / 4 == 0 && (*src).day > 29) || ((*src).year / 4 != 0 && (*src).day > 28))) ||
    (((*src).month == 2 || (*src).month == 4 || (*src).month == 6 || (*src).month == 9 || (*src).month == 11) && (*src).day == 31)) return -1;

    //(*dst) = (*src).year * 10 + (*src).month + (*src).day; "wrong code"

    return 0;
}

int unpack_date (date3_t * dst, pkdate_t date) {
    (*dst).year = date % 10000;
    date = date / 10000;
    (*dst).month = date % 100;
    date = date / 100;
    (*dst).day = date % 100;

    if ((*dst).year < 1097 || (*dst).year > 2097 || (*dst).month < 1 || (*dst).month > 12 || (*dst).day < 1 ||
    ((*dst).month == 2 && (((*dst).year / 4 == 0 && (*dst).day > 29) || ((*dst).year / 4 != 0 && (*dst).day > 28))) ||
    (((*dst).month == 2 || (*dst).month == 4 || (*dst).month == 6 || (*dst).month == 9 || (*dst).month == 11) && (*dst).day == 31)) return -1;
    else return 0;
}

int main () {
    int k = ror(30, 2);
    printf("%s\n", "exercicio 1:");
    printf("%d turned into %d\n", 30, k);

    pkdate_t date = 0;
    date3_t newDate;
    newDate.year = 2000;
    newDate.month = 04;
    newDate.day = 02;
    printf("%s\n", "exercicio 2:");
    //printf("%s\n", "insira uma data (yyyymmdd) e de seguida pressione enter:");

    //int i = 1000;

    //while (i > 0) {
        //newDate.year += getchar() * i;
        //i = i / 10;
    //}

    //i = 10;

    //while (i > 0) {
        //newDate.month += getchar() * i;
        //i = i / 10;
    //}

    //i = 10;

    //while (i > 0) {
        //newDate.day += getchar() * i;
        //i = i / 10;
    //}

    //"the commented part above does not get any values from command line, still figuring that part out :)"

    pack_date(&date, &newDate);

    printf("packed date: %hu\n", date);

    unpack_date(&newDate, date);

    printf("unpacked date: %u/%u/%u\n", newDate.year, newDate.month, newDate.day);

    //newDate.year = 2000;
    //newDate.month = 12;
    //newDate.day = 14;
    //pack_date(&date, &newDate);
    //printf("%s\n", "exercicio 3:");
    //printf("date is %hu\n", date);

    // "ignore"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think of it this way: a year 1970...2097 - 1970 = 0..127 which is a quantity that you can store in 7 bits, leaving you 9 bits to store a month (1..12 needs 4 bits) and a day (1..31 needs 5 bits).  Grand total = 16 bits, so it fits.  Just some shifting (aka multiplying by the appropriate power of 2) and you're done.

Comment: You're going to need 5 bits to represent days of the month 1..31; you're going to need 4 bits to represent months of the year 1..12; that leaves you 7 bits to represent the years 1970..2097, the range of which just happens to be 128, which is also 2^7.  So, you can just about do it.  It seems odd that you have a year test on 1097 instead of 1970.

Comment: Writing out that ghastly test for the validity of a year/month/day twice is a disaster of epic proportions. (OK: I exaggerate a bit, but it is not a good idea.)  It should be a function.  Then you can make the test legible, too, which it currently isn't.  Functions are your friends.  Writing code out twice is, in general, bad; when it is as complex as this, it is very bad.  And the sane way to write `(*dst).day` etc is `dst->day`.  Your leap year calculation is adequate for the range of dates you're dealing with; it is not adequate if the range of dates includes 2100 (or 1900, or …).

Comment: Thanks for your help, and yes, you are absolutely right on the code repetition part, I'm ashamed right now... just kidding xD, but I should be... anyway, that part works fine now, but I still have that problem about the getchar function not getting anything... can you help me with that too please?

Comment: By the way, it is 1970, i wrote it wrong on my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, there aren't so much use cases that qualify for bitfields, but this one is a perfect fit IMHO since it saves you a lot of headaches from bit shifting:

```
struct date_struct
{
    unsigned short year:7;
    unsigned short month:4;
    unsigned short day:5;
};

union date
{
   struct date_struct bits;
   short date;
}
```

Comment: You should use `short`s for the `date_struct`. Otherwise its size will typically be 4 bytes.

Comment: You should use `unsigned short` or `unsigned int` in the `date_struct`; you do not want the values to be signed by accident (and plain types for bit fields are not necessarily signed or unsigned; it is implementation defined — like nearly everything else related to bit fields).  Indeed, using `short` is using implementation-defined behaviour.  The standard says: _A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed
int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type._

Answer (score 0):

First, you should think about how the date should be presented inside this `unsigned short`.

End even firster, you should be aware that the length of a(n unsigned) short is not defined exactly, only its minimum, which is 16 bits.

So let's try to pack such a date into 16 bits.

As already was commented as I write this answer, you can shrink the years into a range of y-1970 = 0..127, which makes you need 7 bits. The months need 4 bits and the days 5, in total 16 bits.

Now think about how you determine the single parts and how you shift them so that they fit.